# Huffman code with very large variety of elements

Tags: algorithm, math, compression, huffman-code

I am trying to implement the Huffman algorithm, as taught in my math class. However, I noticed that in the worst-case scenario, the produced code would be larger than the actual charset encoding.

Currently I only have flowcharts to show. This is strictly a theoretical question.

The issue is that the tree building algorithm does not guarantee a balanced tree where the leaves are evenly distributed, thus minimizing the tree height and therefore, minimizing the produced codeword lengths.

For values of the element frequencies follow a sequence such as Fibonacci's
N1 = 1, N2 = 2, Ni = Ni-1 + Ni-2. 
Nk-1 < Nk < Nk+1 is always true.

when using the following algorithm to build the tree, n - 1 tree levels are needed, where n is the number of elements present:

1. pop the smaller two elements from list
2. make a new node
3. assign both popped nodes to either branch of the new node
4. the weight of the new node is the sum of the weight of its two branches
5. insert new node in list at the appropriate location according to weight
6. repeat until only one node remains

Given that Huffman codewords have a 1:1 relation to the height at which an element is present you would potentially need more bits than the un-compressed encoded character.

Imagine encoding a file written in English. Most of the times there will be more than 10 different characters present. These characters would use 8 bits in ascii or utf-8. However, to encode them using Huffman, in the worst-case scenario you would need up to 9bits. which is worse than the original encoding.

This problem would be exacerbated with larger sets or if you used combinations of characters where the number of possible combinations would be C(n, k), where n is the number of elements present and k is the number of characters to be represented by one codeword.

Obviously, there is something I am missing. I would dearly appreciate an explanation on how to solve this, or links to quality resources where I can learn more. Thank you.

Worst-case scenario:

```
/\
A \
  /\
  B \
    /\
   C  …
      /\
     Y  Z
```

Comment: What you're missing is that the goal is to minimize the `sum of (frequency * code_length)`. So a code of length 9 costs one extra bit if it's only used once `(9-8) * 1 = 1`. But a code of length 5 saves 30 bits if it's used 10 times `(5-8) * 10 = -30`. So in your Fibonacci example, compute the sum and divide by the total number of symbols to see what the average bit count is for each symbol.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just remembered this part of the lecture... Thanks so much!